# How can I tell if a value has been set to undefined or has not been set at all?

Tags: typescript, undefined

I am trying to have a variable that is unset, it's value can be `number` or `undefined` and it's default is completely unset. I want to check if it's unset, and require it to be set.

I run into problems when using a symbol.

```
const unset = Symbol('undefined')

type nething = number | undefined | typeof unset

type x = Exclude<nething, typeof unset>

function notUnset<T extends typeof unset> (t: T): Exclude<T, typeof unset> {
    if (t === unset) throw new Error('is symb')
    return t;
}

let value: number | undefined | typeof unset = unset;
value = 1;

const newValue = notUnset(value);
```

I run into problems using a "TrulyUndefined" class:

```
class TrulyUndefined {}

const unset = new TrulyUndefined();

type nething = number | undefined | typeof unset

type x = Exclude<nething, typeof unset>

function notUnset<T extends TrulyUndefined> (t: T): Exclude<T, TrulyUndefined> {
    if (t instanceof TrulyUndefined) throw new Error('is symb')
    return t;
}

let value: number | undefined | TrulyUndefined = unset;
value = 1;

const newValue = notUnset(value);
```

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: What is that code supposed to do? What is the end goal? Because I am not sure I understand the first snippet - it takes something that is `typeof unset` (so, `Symbol`) and produces something that *isn't* a Symbol by returning the input. The input is, again, a Symbol. It rightly doesn't compile but I'm not sure what should be happening. The second code compiles only because the class is empty. Adding a property to it, say `foo = ""` makes the code fail.

Comment: Note that "I run into problems" by itself does not constitute a sufficient description of your issue.  See the guidelines on [mcve], specifically the part under the subheading "Reproducible" and the subsubheading "Describe the problem".

Comment: I genuinely have no idea what you are trying to accomplish here.  Can you not just use `null` as your third value?  Can you provide an example of where this code is used?  That would help me understand the goal.  For example if you're wanting to find out whether a property of an object is set to `undefined` vs. not set at all, there are better way to do that by looking at the keys.  Or if this a class property maybe there's an additional property that's a `boolean` flag stating whether it has been set.

Comment: @LindaPaiste You got it! Yeah I want a value that identifies a variable is not defined. I can't use `null` or `undefined` or any other structured type because the value may be able to be that type. I would like to ASSIGN an internal type and just simply check of that type is still assigned or not.

Comment: I know there's a convention around this, i've seen it before. 

Answer (score 2):

You mentioned a convention and I wonder if it's the [maybe monad](https://codewithstyle.info/advanced-functional-programming-in-typescript-maybe-monad/)?

I don't think it's possible to determine whether a value is unset from a single variable because you've said the expected type `T` could be anything, so we can't check if a value is `T` or the default because `T` could include the default.

Instead, I propose a pairing where we have two values: the value that we want and a boolean flag which tells us if it is set of not.

```
type MaybeValue<T> = {
    value: T;
    isSet: true;
} | {
    value?: any;
    isSet: false;
}
```

By defining this as a union type, we enforce that if `isSet` is true, the value cannot be empty.  Note that it could be `undefined`, but only if `T` includes `undefined`.

If `isSet` is false then `value` can be anything or nothing.

Here's an example class to interact with this type.  I set the pair to one class property rather than two because it makes it easy to enforce that the two are a valid union assignable to `MaybeValue<T>`.  I also included a chainable `getOrElse` method inspired by the linked article.

```
class MaybeUnset<T extends any> {
    private _maybe: MaybeValue<T>

    // constructor creates empty
    constructor() {
        this._maybe = {
            isSet: false
        }
    }

    // static constructor creates with a value already set
    public static create<T>( value: T): MaybeUnset<T> {
        const obj = new MaybeUnset<T>();
        obj.set( value );
        return obj;
    }

    public set( value: T ) {
        this._maybe = {
            value,
            isSet: true
        }
    }

    public unset() {
        this._maybe = {
            isSet: false
        }
    }

    get isSet(): boolean {
        return this._maybe.isSet;
    }

    public getOrElse<U = T>( fallback: U): T | U {
        if ( this._maybe.isSet ) {
            return this._maybe.value;
        } else {
            return fallback;
        }
    }
}
```

I hope this is a solid starting point for whatever you're trying to do, which I still don't fully understand!

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsghiARhAanANgVwgHgCoB8UAvFAN4CwAUFLVAG4bYBcUeA3NXVAJYDOAZQjBWwAE7ZOVAL5QAPuS51GWCAH5WcAHYgp3fkJFQAZhj4Qp06tQDG6OHz6wEyAKpbzwfFAgAPYBBaACZO2iBElDR0YGI8jAFQAPoAti4QrPBIqEy4hNZRtAD0hVA2APYe4pg2wGVipWIQcAFOEMlgoEq05ZUSNXUAFACUigXcUMAAFvwAdClpJKPjy7yCwqym6OZd41ZjezvFUHzAzTw2pRUnfbX1No3NEE4A7jxTUHAMOR-oD0Egx2EOzAmEQ6HOx1OwAh9yaAXwBAGX1UrDwQwyaXcngRSxWPROUDKiAAVostBBns4sljhAjhnoVkTiTNPEiVNgoEMGctGsBMGItISSdyoAcxiCwRDWciWGxObjllNZvMsotIitxuyIAAaHYagzrCYSCB6uh7bhi7gS8EXTAeYTDBXjJV8OapVWkdUaugGoybbZjC07S10ADmwlWhmGrEQZTK6Cagq9POE-MFLrdaRmvpFIdo1oh4eAAHkxABRLa4VyLQhIzboRBwGwAa1YrnRcoU1eT4x4xigSIzKuQ2bWwHlPY1vLTE2mruHEBmWpFFp8ladU9TApMGAbTebK7Nweo0iAA)